# WorkBox is fetching wrong urlPattern

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, workbox

I'm using **Nuxt.js** framework and my WorkBox config looks like below

```
workbox: {
    workboxURL: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/workbox-sw@4.3.1/build/workbox-sw.min.js',
    cacheAssets: false,
    offline: false,
    runtimeCaching: [
      {
        urlPattern: '^/$|/(?:about|contact)$',
        handler: 'cacheFirst',
        strategyOptions: {
          cacheName: 'test-cache-v1',
          cacheExpiration: {
            maxEntries: 5,
            maxAgeSeconds: 10
          }
        }
      },
      {
        urlPattern: '/.*',
        handler: 'networkOnly',
      },
    ]
}
```

Here `urlPattern: '^/$|/(?:about|contact)$'` suppose to match all 3 requests:

```
/
/about
/contact
```

But only `/about` and `/contact` is matched and `/` is being handled by next cache strategy `urlPattern: '/.*'` which is networkOnly.

Not sure why WorkBox is not able to handle `/` request in `cacheFirst` strategy

This what **ServiceWork.js** file content looks like

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('^/$|/(?:about|contact)$'), workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({"cacheName":"test-cache-v1","cacheExpiration":{"maxEntries":5,"maxAgeSeconds":10}}), 'GET')

workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('/.*'), workbox.strategies.networkOnly({}), 'GET')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WorkBox is running RegExp on **event.request.url** which returns full URL like `http://localhost:3000` instead of relative path.

So wildcard `^/$` was not able to handle the request. I fixed the issue by replacing my RegExp from `^/$` to `^http://localhost:3000[/]?$`